# SQL Query - Replace NULL with Text IF Date Older than 30 days

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

**Version**: SQL Server 2008 R2

I'm currently receiving output like the following:

```
f_ID     f_lastonline         f_reasonforoffline
===============================================================
1        01/01/2015 12:00:00  ISP Down
2        02/02/2015 12:00:00  Hardware Failure
3        03/03/2015 12:00:00  NULL
4        04/23/2015 12:00:00  NULL
```

I can replace NULL values by default with a string of my choice using

```
SELECT
  f_ID,
  f_lastonline,
  ISNULL(f_reasonforoffline, 'Likely Turned Off') AS f_reasonforoffline
```

This query syntax would return the output like the following:

```
f_ID     f_lastonline         f_reasonforoffline
===============================================================
1        01/01/2015 12:00:00  ISP Down
2        02/02/2015 12:00:00  Hardware Failure
3        03/03/2015 12:00:00  Likely Turned Off
4        04/23/2015 12:00:00  Likely Turned Off
```

However, I would like to ONLY change the text to 'Likely Turned Off' if the 'f_lastonline' date is older than, say, 30 days.

To explain in code (but note that this is syntactically-incorrect), this is what I'm hoping to accomplish:

```
ISNULL(IF f_lastonline <= DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()),-30) THEN f_reasonforoffline, 'Likely Turned Off' ELSE f_reasonforoffline, '') AS f_reasonforoffline,
```

The final desired output, then, would be the following where the NULL 'f_reasonforoffline' from 03/03/2015 (that is older than 30 days) would be changed to 'Likely Turned Off' and the NULL 'f_reasonforoffline' value from 04/23/2015 would simply be changed to '' (not null, just blank).

```
f_ID     f_lastonline         f_reasonforoffline
===============================================================
1        01/01/2015 12:00:00  ISP Down
2        02/02/2015 12:00:00  Hardware Failure
3        03/03/2015 12:00:00  Likely Turned Off
4        04/23/2015 12:00:00
```

*NOTE: The reason for doing this is so that I don't have to explain what "NULL" means anymore to people looking at reports.

Thanks in advance,
Beems

Comment: Thanks, I did look into it and that solved my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  f_ID,
  f_lastonline,
  CASE 
    WHEN f_lastonline < DATEADD(DD,-30,GETDATE()) 
    THEN ISNULL(f_reasonforoffline, 'Likely Turned Off') 
    ELSE f_reasonforoffline 
  END AS f_reasonforoffline
```

Comment: Gave you the acceptance since I didn't see your response prior to posting mine. I've edited yours for formatting and deleted my own answer.

Comment: Your humble nature has astounded me. Thank you sir.